# 'mat-label' is not a known element creando un componente en Angular 8

Tags: angular

Estoy creando una librería con angular 8 de acuerdo a la [documentación](https://angular.io/guide/creating-libraries).

mi module.ts tiene el siguiente código:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { NeoMatTableComponent } from './neo-mat-table.component';
import { MatFormFieldModule, MatInputModule, MatPaginatorModule, MatSortModule, MatTableModule } from '@angular/material';
import { ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';



@NgModule({
  declarations: [NeoMatTableComponent],
  imports: [
    MatFormFieldModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    MatInputModule,
    MatSortModule,
    MatTableModule,
    MatPaginatorModule,
    CommonModule
  ],
  exports: [NeoMatTableComponent]
})
export class NeoMatTableModule { }
```

Sí, estoy importando MatFormFieldModule y no tengo otro module.